# Помогите создать скрипт на базе (.vbs)

Tags: vbscript

Как сделать что бы программа Radmin запускалась в скрытом режиме и ее невозможно было бы где увидеть кроме как в диспетчере задач?

```vb
' метод wscript run 
' Запуск блокнота и передача ему текста
' run_1.vbs
  
Option Explicit

dim WshShell

' Создаем ссылку на объект Wscript.Shell
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

' Запускаем блокнот и вставляем в него текст сценария
WshShell.Run "notepad.exe " & WScript.ScriptFullName,1,true

Wscript.Echo "Это был запуск программы блокнот"
```

и то он не подошел

```vb
path = "C:\Windows\12_12\"
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run path & "Radmin.exe", ,true
```

Напишите что нужно сделать, или пример такого запуска.

Comment: Ваш скрипт блокируется хромом. Вставьте его прямо в тело вопроса.

Comment: Исправил как вы попросили

Comment: MSDN сам же говорит что параметр intWindowStyle Integer value indicating the appearance of the program's window. Note that not all programs make use of this information.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял условие:

```
set t=createobject("Wscript.Shell")
t.run "notepad.exe",0
```

-запускает блокнот, который виден исключительно в диспетчере задач